# Why two different buffer for a same string?

Tags: node.js, string, hex, buffer

I am trying to convert a string to buffer using nodejs. The string is here :

```
\xf5\x89\xf8\x19+q@o\xa7\xdcwa2\x8f@\x0c\xd1\x14\x8bT6u@~a]HG\x83
```

When I am doing this from console, I get a simple buffer. But if I read that from a text file, the corresponding buffer results in a different way. I am working with the following code :

```
var data = '\xf5\x89\xf8\x19+q@o\xa7\xdcwa2\x8f@\x0c\xd1\x14\x8bT6u@~a]HG\x83';
const buf = Buffer.from(data, 'ascii');    // Converting string to buffer
console.log(buf);
// While reading from file
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('notes.txt', function (err,data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Is it possible to get the same buffer in both way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the data variable you declare this value "\xf5\x89\xf8\x19+q@o\xa7\xdcwa2\x8f@\x0c\xd1\x14\x8bT6u@~a]HG\x83"

where "\" character does not count when you convert it to Buffer.

Please use  double  back slash. See example:

```
var data = '\\xf5\\x89\\xf8\\x19+q@o\\xa7\\xdcwa2\\x8f@\\x0c\\xd1\\x14\\x8bT6u@~a]HG\\x83';
```